# FullCalendar.js not firing consistently over JS/Ajax/ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

This is a tricky one so I'll be as informative as I can. I have [FullCalendar.js](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) running as a JS calendar plugin on an external page "calendar_summary.cfm" which is called as part of a series of other pages which reload over various periods of time on a singular page. This calendar summary page has data which is called via ColdFusion into a JS object to feed the data into FullCalendar.js. The results of that are carried over AJAX to appear in a DIV on the main page (which we will call "main_page.cfm").

Problem is, the calendar call doesn't always fire all the time when "calendar_summary.cfm" is called, resulting in a blank space within the "calendar" DIV within the now populated "content2" DIV of "main_page.cfm", other times, the $("#calendar").fullCalendar() call fires showing a lovely calendar. Any ideas where I may be going wrong? Code below:

From the main_page.cfm (ColdFusion/JS/jQuery):

```
<script>
function jsAjax(theUrl,theClass) {
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        context: document.body,
        success: function(responseText) {
            $("."+theClass).html(responseText);
            $("."+theClass).find("script").each(function(i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });
        }
    });
};

function ajax(){
    try{
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        return xmlHttp;
    }
    catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
            return xmlHttp;
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                return xmlHttp;
            }
            catch (e){
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function fetch_unix_timestamp()
{
    return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10));
}
function ref_kr_status(){
    var divid = "content2";
    var url = "calendar_summary.cfm";

    var xml3 = ajax();
    var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
    var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

    xml3.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xml3.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xml3.responseText;
            setTimeout('ref_kr_status();jsAjax("calendar_summary.cfm","content2");',60e3);
        }
    }
    xml3.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
    xml3.send(null);
}

window.onload = function startrefresh(){
    setTimeout('ref_kr_status();',60e3);
}
</script>
<div class="content2" id="content2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
ref_kr_status();jsAjax("calendar_summary.cfm","content2");
</script>
```

From "calendar_summary.cfm" (also ColdFusion/JS/jQuery)

```
<cfoutput>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="color: white; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,88,138,1) 0%, rgba(0,60,94,1) 50%, rgba(0,88,138,1) 100%);"><th colspan="5">Calendar for #DateFormat(Now(),"mmmm, yyyy")#</th></tr><tr><td><cfquery name="qJobs" datasource="kxxxxs">SELECT j.*, IFNULL(c.color_hex, 'FF00FF') AS color_hex, s.job_status_desc as status
        FROM jobs j
        LEFT OUTER JOIN installers i
            ON i.installer_id = j.job_installer
        LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c
            ON c.color_id = i.installer_color
        LEFT OUTER JOIN job_status s
            ON s.job_status_id = j.job_status
        WHERE j.job_install_date_start IS NOT NULL
        AND j.job_install_date_end IS NOT NULL
        AND j.job_active = 1
</cfquery>
<cfsavecontent variable="theCal">
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $("##calendar").html("");
    while ($("##calendar").html()==""){
        $("##calendar").fullCalendar(
            {height: 400, 
            header: {left: "",center: " ",right: ""},
            editable: false,
            events: [
            <cfloop query="qJobs">
                <cfset dateStart = qJobs.job_install_date_start />
                <cftry>
                    <cfset dateEnd = qJobs.job_install_date_end />
                    <cfcatch type="any">
                        <cfset dateEnd = qJobs.job_install_date_start />
                    </cfcatch>
                </cftry>
                <cfset _year1 = Year(dateStart) />
                <cfset _month1 = Month(dateStart) />
                <cfset _day1 = Day(dateStart) />
                <cfset _hour1 = Hour(dateStart) />
                <cfset _minute1 = Minute(dateStart) />
                <cfset _year2 = Year(dateEnd) />
                <cfset _month2 = Month(dateEnd) />
                <cfset _day2 = Day(dateEnd) />
                <cfset _hour2 = Hour(dateEnd) />
                <cfset _minute2 = Minute(dateEnd) />
                <cfset backgroundColorText = 'backgroundColor: "###qJobs.color_hex#",' />
                <cfset titleText = 'title: "#qJobs.job_name#",' />
                {id: "#qJobs.job_id#", 
                    #titleText#
                    start: new Date(#_year1#, #(_month1-1)#, #_day1#, #_hour1#, #_minute1#),
                    end: new Date(#_year2#, #(_month2-1)#, #_day2#, #_hour2#, #_minute2#),
                    allDay: <cfif (DateDiff("s", dateEnd, dateStart) GE 86400)>true<cfelse>false</cfif>,
                    <cfif job_completed EQ 0>#backgroundColorText#<cfelse>backgroundColor: "##999999",</cfif>
                    borderColor: "##000000",
                    textColor: "##ffffff"}
                    <cfif qJobs.CurrentRow NEQ qJobs.RecordCount>,</cfif>
            </cfloop>]
            }
        );
    }
</cfsavecontent>

<table style="width: 725px; font-size: 12px !important;">
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td>
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </td>
<script type='text/javascript' id="doThat">
    #theCal#
</script>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing that's resulting in that calendar function to not fire every so often?

Many thanks in advance...

~ Eliseo

Comment: Have you tried using firebug or chrome dev tools to see if the Ajax request is firing? Look for the network requests or add some console.log directives in some key places to really see where it's going wrong. Also if you are using query any reason you are doing the Ajax request manually? Why not use jquery to make life easier?

Comment: @SeanCoyne I've tried that, but it's been a little diffuclt to track... However, I have been monitoring the changes I made inspired by your suggestion of using `$(document).ready()` and it seems to be working a lot better. Given the nature of the data being fed into it, the slight delay still is workable in this situation...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the calendar initialization code within an `onload` function or jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){});`

That is most likely why sometimes it "fires" and sometimes it doesn't.  It would depend on how the browser is loading your code.  You might get lucky and the relevant parts of the DOM are loaded when the JS is executed and other times it might fire before the DOM is fully loaded and since the `<div>` isn't there it seems as though it doesn't fire.  So, if you move it into a on load function, you can ensure that it will not fire until after the DOM is fully loaded.  [More info on jQuery's API docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)